# Did genocide occur in the Football War?

Tags: genocide

In the [Football War](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Football_War) between El Salvador and Honduras, the El Salvador claimed that genocide had occurred in Honduras. However, was anybody actually prosecuted for these actions, or were these claims unfounded?

Comment: Going by the wikipedia page, it doesn't look like a credible claim. Note that it was made *before* the start of the hostilities. It seems that the Honduran government was engaged in a sort of nasty and brutal land grab versus ethnic Salvadorans who lived there but genocide is way too tall a word for that. But that's just based on wikipedia - maybe there is a dimension I missed here.

Comment: Could someone please explain how Salvadorans are ethnicly different from Hondurans?  Isn't it rather like the ethnic difference between... oh, North and South Dakotans?

Comment: which of the few dozen genocide definitions do you mean?

Comment: It is not uncommon for warring countries to accuse each other of genocide and atrocities. A more recent example would be Russian-Georgian war in Ossetia in which Russians led a huge (false and unfounded) campaign that Georgians were committing Genocide which was later disproved. (But Georgians in Ossetia did get Ethnically wiped out)

Comment: I suspect that the Salvadorean government is more likely to have committed genocide against Salvadoreans than the government of Honduras, and that the government of Honduras is more likely to have committed genocide against Hondurans than against Salvadoreans.

Answer (score 1):

This wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Football_War#Buildup) states:

"stating that 'the government of Honduras has not taken any effective measures to punish these crimes which constitute genocide, nor has it given assurances of indemnification or reparations for the damages caused to Salvadorans'"
- Wikipedia, Football War, Buildup, and Anderson, Thomas P. The War of the Dispossessed: Honduras and El Salvador 1969. p.105 Lincoln: University of Nebraska Press, 1981.

It's possible they might have, but they haven't released any such figures.